# Match all lines that contain the words the, not as part of a substring but as a whole word

Tags: unix

I'm trying to get the word "the" by itself: this is what I got so far:

grep -i "the" ithaka.txt

However, I keep getting words that have "the" in them. For example: "these".
How can I get "the" by itself?

Comment: ithaka.txt is my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the grep man page for the BSD version of grep available on macOS:

> -w, --word-regexp
> The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]' and` [[:>:]]'; see
> re_format(7)).

This option should likely be available in the version of grep you are using unless it is like the bare bones POSIX version or something.

```
grep -w "the" ithaka.txt
```

You can use `man grep` to find out more options available on your specific grep version.